# having trouble launching a launch file from another launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I’ve created a catkin workspace and so far it includes one package. This package has a cpp file as a node which uses API function from other package (youbot APIs).  So far it has worked well and it can drive my robot (Kuka youbot).
Now I want to call a launch file of other package (e.g. Kinect Xbox) from the launch of the pack I have already created. To do this I did following steps:
1-  I created a catkin workspace named youbot_kinect_test which includes ‘build’, ‘devel’,’src’.
2-  In ‘src’ there is the first package named ’ main_node’ including main.cpp, package.xml, Cmakelists.txt and Launch folder.
3-  In the launch folder I put a launch file which includes another launch file(the Kinect launch file) as follow:

'

'

But my problem is that when I run roslaunch main_node Kinect_test.launch I receive this error:

while processing /opt/ros/hydro/share/freenect_launch/opt/ros/hydro/share/freenect_launch/freenect.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/hydro/share/freenect_launch/opt/ros/hydro/share/freenect_launch/freenect.launch'

Now my question is that is it possible to call a launch file from another? Do I have to change and edit the package.xml? Is it correct to put the launch file in the main_node package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200420/having-trouble-launching-a-launch-file-from-another-launch-file/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe is should be like `<include file="$(find freenect_launch)/launch/freenect.launch"/>`

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2015-01-05**:
Many thanks. My problem is solved but would you please explain why? Why mine was not correct? Is it because the command 'find' has already included " freenect_launch" package and there is no need for writing whole directory?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-05**:
If you do `roscd freenect_launch` it will take you to `/opt/ros/<distro>/share` that is basically what `$(find freenect_launch)` does thus you do not need to include it.  Once in the correct directory, you need to advance to launch and then the file.launch.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2015-01-05**:
Thanks. I got it.